# Whats the best method to test the serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, mocking, moq

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Mailer {
    public class ClientConfiguration {

        public virtual bool Save(string fileName) {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClientConfiguration));
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName)) {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I would like to stub/mock the serializer.Serialize method to ensure that the method is called. I've tried so many way with moq and NMock but failed.

Please help me in stub/mocking the calls to the serializer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you use Typemock Isolator or Moles, you can't replace anything which is internally created with the `new` keyword.

You'll need to first extract an interface from the XmlSerializer and then inject that into the class.

As an example, you might introduce this interface:

```
public interface IXmlSerializer
{
    public void Serialize(Stream stream, object o);
}
```

Inject that into your Mailer class like this:

```
public class ClientConfiguration
{
    private readonly IXmlSerializer serializer;

    public ClientConfiguration(IXmlSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (serializer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serializer");
        }
        this.serializer = serializer;
    }

    public virtual bool Save(string fileName)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            this.serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now you can inject the mock into the class:

```
var mock = new Mock<IXmlSerializer>();
var sut = new ClientConfiguration(mock.Object);
```

The above example uses Moq.

Comment: Beautiful implementation of SRP!

Comment: There's nothing like trawling Google for an XmlSerializer interface and then seeing how simple it is to knock one up yourself!  Thanks!

Comment: How come you passed object of type StreamWriter to the Serialize method that expects object of type Stream? Shouldn't it be writer.BaseStream instead?

Comment: @havekar You're probably right. It may have been one of those answers I threw up there without actually having tried to compile it...